# making a patch between two commits

Tags: git, patch

This is a simple question but only to avoid confusion because in the other answers there is a little detail everyone forgot

If I have a commit history like this

```
1111 (HEAD->FeatureBranch)  one change
2222  another change
3333 more changes
4444 my first change
5555 (original_branch) the last common change
```

and I want to send my patch to another developer who has until the last common change, what is the *order* in which I should do the git diff?

```
git diff FeatureBranch original_branch >thepatch.diff
```

or the other way around? (original_branch FeatureBranch)

Any other ways to do a patch welcome too

Comment: use `git format-patch original_branch`?

Comment: I suppose that I do it from `FeatureBranch`?

Comment: Yes, that would make sense. Have a go and see if the output works for you?

Comment: Assuming you want to send the *individual commits*, `git format-patch` is the answer. Assuming you want to send a single diff that's not related to the commits you made, but achieves the same result, `git diff` is the answer, and the *order* of the arguments to `git diff` is <commit1> <commit2> where <commit1> represents what *they have* (i.e., hash `5555`) and <commit2> represents the snapshot you'd like them to get after they apply the patch you send them (so probably `1111` here).

Comment: If a commit has a *name* that selects it, you can use that name *instead of* the hash ID. The reason is that most Git commands run the names through `git rev-parse`, which you can test out yourself: run `git rev-parse main`, `git rev-parse FeatureBranch`, `git rev-parse 1111`, and so on, and see what comes out. The purpose of the names is to allow you (and Git) to find a commit by name; but the hash ID you'll get from some branch name is always the *latest* commit in that branch. The hash IDs *never change* and *every Git repository everywhere* uses the *same hash ID* for the same commit.

Comment: This means that a raw hash ID—the full one that is—works *everywhere and every time*. The repository either has that commit, and then it has that hash ID, or it does not have that commit at all and therefore does not have that hash ID (in which case nothing at all can work: you will have to get that commit from a repository that *does* have it). But hash IDs are difficult for humans, so we use names. A *branch* name means "the latest one", which evolves over time.